# Rotating iOS UILayer like a ticking clock, not smoothly in a circle

Tags: ios, core-animation

I am able to rotate an image a certain number of degrees continuously, but I want to rotate the image a tiny amount, pause, a little more, pause, etc.

The follow code does this continuously:

```
// rotate
CGFloat finalValue = 360 / 14.f;
CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
[rotationAnimation setFromValue:[self degreesToNumber:0]];
[rotationAnimation setToValue:[self degreesToNumber:finalValue]];
[rotationAnimation setDuration:5.0];
[rotationAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[rotationAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[self.secondHandImageView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotate"];
```

Is there a way to wrap this in a for-loop with the number of angle changes I need and set the duration and delay of the specific animations? Nothing I have tried works. Below is what I am currently trying:

```
// rotate in ticks, so
NSTimeInterval delay = 0;
CGFloat currentAngle = 0;
CGFloat finalAngle = 360 / 14.f;

// angle difference
CGFloat numberOfTicks = 25.f;
CGFloat angleDelta = finalAngle / numberOfTicks;

for (NSUInteger tick = 0; tick < numberOfTicks; tick++) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:delay options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        self.secondHandImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0, 0, angleDelta, 1.0);
    } completion:nil];

    // update delay
    delay += .2; // 200 milliseconds, 5 tickets every second
    currentAngle += angleDelta;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is OK - except that you can't animate layers inside UIView animation blocks. Instead you can animate the view. Replace the  (3D)layer transform with a (2D)view transform:

```
 self.secondHandImageView.transform = 
      CGAffineTransformRotate(self.tickView.transform,angleDelta);
```